# C# EF CF relaciones uno a zero o uno

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Estoy intentando hacer un modelo relacional entre varias clases con EF Code First y no logro hacer que el modelo funcione. La idea del modelo es recrear el depósito de n documentos y guardar el historial del documento y asociarlo al depósito.

Tengo 4 modelos:

```
-Cheque
-HistorialMovimiento
-RelHistorialDeposito
-Deposito
```

Los modelos se relacionan así

`.            [Cheque]1--------n[HistorialMovimiento]
 [HistorialMovimiento]1-----0..1[RelHistorialDeposito]
[RelHistorialDeposito]n--------1[Deposito]`

```cs
public class HistorialMovimiento
{
    [Key]
    public int IdHistorial { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Cheque")]
    public int IdCheque { get; set; }
    public virtual Cheque Cheque { get; set; }

    public virtual RelHistorialDeposito HistorialDeposito { get; set; }
}

public class RelHistorialDeposito
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Historial")]
    public int IdHistorial { get; set; }
    public virtual HistorialMovimiento Historial { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Deposito")]
    public int IdDeposito { get; set; }
    public virtual Deposito Deposito { get; set; }
}

public class Deposito
{
    [Key]
    public int IdDeposito { get; set; }

    public virtual List<RelHistorialDeposito> RelHistorialDeposito { get; set; }
}
```

En el DBContext tengo:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RelHistorialDeposito>().HasKey(k => new { k.IdHistorial, k.IdDeposito });
modelBuilder.Entity<RelHistorialDeposito>().HasRequired(r => r.Historial).WithOptional(h => h.HistorialDeposito);
```

Pero al tratar de preparar la migración me aparece esto:

> RelHistorialDeposito_Historial_Source: : La multiplicidad no es válida
>   en el rol (Role) 'RelHistorialDeposito_Historial_Source' de la
>   relación 'RelHistorialDeposito_Historial'. Como las propiedades de
>   Dependent Role no son las propiedades de clave, el límite superior de
>   la multiplicidad de Dependent Role debe ser '*'.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve leyendo y encontré un detalle importante, en las relaciones uno a cero o uno, la tabla dependiente **debe** tener como clave principal el id de la tabla independiente.

Entonces tenia que arreglar el modelo y el dbContext:

```cs
public class HistorialMovimiento
{
    [Key]
    public int IdHistorial { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Cheque")]
    public int IdCheque { get; set; }
    public virtual Cheque Cheque { get; set; }

    public virtual RelHistorialDeposito HistorialDeposito { get; set; }
}

public class RelHistorialDeposito
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Historial")]
    public int IdHistorial { get; set; }
    public virtual HistorialMovimiento Historial { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Deposito")] // Cambio Importante
    public int IdDeposito { get; set; }
    public virtual Deposito Deposito { get; set; }
}

public class Deposito
{
    [Key]
    public int IdDeposito { get; set; }

    public virtual List<RelHistorialDeposito> RelHistorialDeposito { get; set; }
}
```

Y en el dbContext hay que quitar la llave compuesta:

```
//Comentando esta linea, se acaba el problema
//modelBuilder.Entity<RelHistorialDeposito>().HasKey(k => new { k.IdHistorial, k.IdDeposito });
modelBuilder.Entity<RelHistorialDeposito>().HasRequired(r => r.Historial).WithOptional(h => h.HistorialDeposito);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que pruebas EF Core siento que tiene mejores cualidades, pero bueno dejando eso a un lado veo que usas Data Annotations y no te lo recomiendo, es preferible usar FluentApi y configurar las entidades en una clase de configuracion que herede de EntityTypeConfiguration. 
Yo te recomiendo seguir las **convenciones**, y con lo de la relación basta hacer lo siguiente.

```
public class Historial
{
    public int HistorialId { get; set; }
    public int ChequeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Cheque Cheque { get; set; }
    public int? HistorialDepositoId { get; set; }
    public virtual RelHistorialDeposito HistorialDeposito { get; set; }
}

public class HistorialDeposito
{
    public int HistorialDeposito { get; set; }
    public int DepositoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Deposito Deposito { get; set; }
}
```

Yo lo veo de esta forma, ya que solo debes de colocar signo ? para que acepte nulos la propiedad que seria la llave foránea de la tabla Historial.
Si necesitas la propiedad navegacional al otro extremo de la relación es decir en la tabla HistorialDeposito basta con que hagas lo mismo